# Como posso criar um esquema de abas com react hooks?

Tags: react, react-hooks

Estou criando um sistema, e ao invés de colocar as 'sub categorias' de cadastros abaixo do menu, estou criando como abas, quando você clica em cada menu e então possui os demais acessos.

Exemplo: ao clicar em Cadastros, atualiza o meu conteúdo ao lado com 'abas'(Listgroup) de todos os tipos de cadastros que vou ter. Gostaria que ao selecionar estes itens(cadastro 1, cadastros 2 ... na imagem)atualizasse o conteúdo da página com os campos de formulários.
Pesquisei pelo `useState` do react, mas não consegui entender como implementar ele nesta rotina, poderiam me ajudar?

As minhas abas, eu fiz como uma lista na horizontal, utilizando o componente do react-botstrap (Listgroup).

```
<ListGroup horizontal>
    <ListGroup.Item variant="info">teste 1</ListGroup.Item>
    <ListGroup.Item variant="info">teste 2</ListGroup.Item>
    <ListGroup.Item variant="info">teste 3</ListGroup.Item>
    <ListGroup.Item variant="info">teste 4</ListGroup.Item>
    <ListGroup.Item variant="info">teste 5</ListGroup.Item>
    <ListGroup.Item variant="primary">teste 6</ListGroup.Item>
</ListGroup>
```

Ao selecionar um destes itens, gostaria que atualizasse o `Card`.

```
<Card>
  <Card.Header>
    <Card.Title as="h4">Mudar o conteúdo aqui</Card.Title>
    <p className="card-category">
      Conteúdo aqui
    </p>
  </Card.Header>
  <Card.Body>
    ffff
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
```

Estou utilizando:
`NodeJs 14.15.5`
`React-bootstrap`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Há dois caminhos para resolver isso, seguir com a forma que você iniciou e usar o useState ou utilizar o componente tab do Bootstrap que já tem o comportamento mais parecido com o que você deseja.

## Adicionando useState ao seu código

O useState permite que você adicione um valor ao seu componente que você pode modificar mediante ações como o click, por exemplo. Eu fiz um exemplo seguindo o seu código:

```
import React from 'react'
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'

const counteudos = [
   'Conteudo 1',
   'Conteudo 2',
   'Conteudo 3',
   'Conteudo 4',
   'Conteudo 5',
   'Conteudo 6',
]

export default function App() {
  const [abaAtiva, setAbaAtiva] = React.useState(0)

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ListGroup horizontal>
        <ListGroup.Item onClick={() => setAbaAtiva(0)} variant={abaAtiva === 0 ? 'primary' : 'info'}>teste 1</ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item onClick={() => setAbaAtiva(1)} variant={abaAtiva === 1 ? 'primary' : 'info'}>teste 2</ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item onClick={() => setAbaAtiva(2)} variant={abaAtiva === 2 ? 'primary' : 'info'}>teste 3</ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item onClick={() => setAbaAtiva(3)} variant={abaAtiva === 3 ? 'primary' : 'info'}>teste 4</ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item onClick={() => setAbaAtiva(4)} variant={abaAtiva === 4 ? 'primary' : 'info'}>teste 5</ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item onClick={() => setAbaAtiva(5)} variant={abaAtiva === 5 ? 'primary' : 'info'}>teste 6</ListGroup.Item>
      </ListGroup>

      <Card>
        <Card.Header>
          <Card.Title as="h4">Mudar o conteúdo aqui</Card.Title>
          <p className="card-category">
            {counteudos[abaAtiva]}
          </p>
        </Card.Header>
        <Card.Body>
          ffff
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
  </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

[Sandbox com esse código rodando](https://codesandbox.io/s/exemplo-usando-list-items-e-card-0l37d?file=/src/App.js)

## Solução alternativa: Tabs

Com o componente Tabs do Bootstrap é possível fazer o que você quer sem necessariamente precisar do uso de estado.
O [primeiro exemplo da documentação](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/#tabs-examples) é bastante parecido com o que você deseja. O Código das Tabs ficaria algo como:

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="1">
  <Tab eventKey="1" title="test 1">
    Conteudo 1
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="2" title="test 2">
    Conteudo 2
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="3" title="test 3">
    Conteudo 3
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```